# How can I add n number of datetime.strptime in "%I:%M:%S" format stored in a list in python

Tags: python, list, datetime, strptime

I've n number of `datetime.strptime` items stored in a list in `"%I:%M:%S"` format

`total_logs = ['0:00:12', '0:10:02', , , n]`

How can I add them?

Comment: You mean add them to each other? What have you tried? How would you add regular numbers in a list to each other? Do the same thing with the datetime objects after you've parsed the strings.

Comment: try something like `sum([datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%I:%M:%S") for i in total_logs])`

Comment: @Ghost Ops, I tried your method but there is a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: Could you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Timedelta class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) from `pandas` to do this.

```
import pandas as pd

logs = ['0:00:12', '0:10:02']
r = pd.Timedelta(logs[0]) + pd.Timedelta(logs[1])
print(r)
```

Output: `0 days 00:10:14`

Python's `datetime.timedelta` could also do the job, but it doesn't work on strings directly. You have to convert them using `datetime.datetime.strptime` first.

To sum all the items in the list, you have to start from a starting point, in the following code it is `r`, then you iterate over the list and you add to `r`:

```
In [37]: r = pd.Timedelta(0)

In [38]: r
Out[38]: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')

In [39]: for item in logs:
    ...:     r += pd.Timedelta(item)
    ...:

In [40]: print(r)
0 days 00:10:14
```

The one-liner for the whole think would be: `sum(map(pd.Timedelta, logs), pd.Timedelta(0))`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.
But how to convert this code for 'n' number of items in the list?

Comment: @MilindKhobragade check the updated answer